# How can I save my changes in activity?

Tags: android

I do some changes in my activity and start other activity but when I come back activity changes gone. How can I save my changes?

I do this when clicking a button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    e_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    key.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

});
```

and redirect to another activity.

Comment: What exactly is the question? There is pretty much no context to it..

Comment: I want to disappear the objects when I click the button and When I came back to the objects should be gone?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with the layout what you have currently then call do the same in `OnResume()` . It will work for you.

```
@Override
public void onResume()
 {
    super.onResume();
    btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    e_mail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    key.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    username.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    edt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not necessarily what he's after, as it would automatically hide all objects upon the first run too (prior to the click).